# Printing Pattern for a Class Hierarchy in the C++ FAQ

Tags: c++, printing, iostream, hierarchy

I am implementing the [printing pattern for a class hierarchy](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/virtual-friend-fns.html) as described in the [C++ FAQ](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/). In the FAQ, the printing function is declared in the base class like this:

```cpp
protected:
  virtual void printOn(std::ostream& o) const = 0;  // pure virtual
  // -- or --
  virtual void printOn(std::ostream& o) const;      // plain virtual
```

I am considering implementing the plain virtual version of the `printOn` method but with a variation. I would like to change the return type from `void` to `std::ostream&` as shown here:

```cpp
protected:
  virtual std::ostream& printOn(std::ostream& o) const;
```

The advantage of this approach as I see it would be to allow the output of a base class to be more easily incorporated into that of a derived class using a **chaining approach**. Here's an example:

```cpp
std::ostream& DerivedClass::printOn(std::ostream& stream) const
{
  return stream
      << "<DerivedClass>" << '\n'
      << BaseClass::printOn(stream)
      << "<member_one>" << member_one_ << "</member_one>" << '\n'
      << "<member_two>" << member_two_ << "</member_two>" << '\n'
      << "</DerivedClass>" << std::endl;
}
```

In contrast, here's how `DerivedClass::printOn` might look if the virtual `BaseClass::printOn` method is declared `void` as shown in the FAQ:

```cpp
void DerivedClass::printOn(std::ostream& stream) const
{
    stream << "<DerivedClass>" << '\n';
    BaseClass::printOn(stream);

    stream
        << "<member_one>" << member_one_ << "</member_one>" << '\n'
        << "<member_two>" << member_two_ << "</member_two>" << '\n'
        << "</DerivedClass>" << std::endl;
}
```

**QUESTION:** Does anyone see any pitfalls with my proposed revision to the return type of `printOn`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `BaseClass::printOn(stream)` returns a `std::ostream &` then you can't write

```
stream << ... << BaseClass::printOn(stream) << ...;
```

You'd have to write:

```
stream << ...;
BaseClass::printOn(stream) << ...;
```

Clearly, this is barely any better than the case where it returns `void`.  You could return a type with a no-op stream-out operator:

```
struct noop_manipulator {
  noop_manipulator(std::ostream &) {}
  friend inline std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const noop_manipulator &) {
    return os;
  }
};

noop_manipulator DerivedClass::printOn(std::ostream& stream) const
{
    return stream << ...;
}
```

Alternatively, you can just play around with syntax:

```
void DerivedClass::printOn(std::ostream& stream) const
{
    return stream << "<DerivedClass>" << '\n',
        BaseClass::printOn(stream), stream
        << "<member_one>" << member_one_ << "</member_one>" << '\n'
        << "<member_two>" << member_two_ << "</member_two>" << '\n'
        << "</DerivedClass>" << std::endl;
}
```

The downside to all these approaches is that they obscure your use of a superclass virtual call, which is sufficiently unusual that it really should be made as clear as possible.  The described printing pattern is itself fairly unusual; unless you have a virtual inheritance hierarchy already, it's more usual for derived classes to have their own `operator<<` and call the base class `operator<<` via `static_cast` to base class reference.

Comment: @DavidRR syntactically you're calling `ostream << ostream`, which isn't specifically defined but will typically invoke the `operator void *` fail-check operator.  You should expect to see a pointer value in the output stream.

Comment: Yes, after I actually prototyped what I had proposed, it did indeed become clear to me that I ended up invoking `ostream << ostream`. And I am indeed now developing a virtual inheritance hierarchy from scratch and I felt the printing pattern recommended by the C++ FAQ was a good fit. I will also keep in mind your recommended alternative approach to override `operator<<` in an a derived class.